# make a c# connection to mysql running on linux virtual box from visual studio 2017 community

Tags: c#, mysql, virtualbox

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community and I'm trying to make a c# connection to my MySQL database running on a virtual box ( linux Ubuntu ).

I added the MySQL.Data to the references and added 'using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;'.

Does anyone have a code example from their own project or something that has actually worked. None of the tutorial ones I've used so far have worked and each connection string looks slightly different from the others.

Here's what I have at this stage...

```
string myConnectionString = "datasource=192.168.1.102;port=3306;username=xxxxx;password=yyyyy;";
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection( myConnectionString );

try {
    myConnection.Open();
}
catch( Exception error ) {
    MessageBox.Show( error.Message );
}
finally {
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What `doesnt work` mean do you have any error message? and never put your login/password in questions.insted use something like `xxxxxx`

Comment: The error message I get is "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

Comment: Check here for the string connection https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ you are missing the database name, also you need to check if server is up and allow external conenction (firewall) and double check the db server port.

Comment: Hello @Ivan. Have you ensured that your MySql server is actually listening to port 3306? You can verify this using a number of methods, but the netstat utility should work fine from command line.

Comment: ok, adjusted the connection string. The server is up and running, and I've disabled the firewall on my linux machine and my pc (just to test). The port is the 3306 which I double checked. No luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to config file

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

change

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

to

```
#bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

also be sure that port is set to 3306

```
port=3306
```

then restart your server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped me sort out that problem. Now I just need to figure out the next one. I ended up using a different path as to what you specified... I used /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and then followed the rest of the instructions as is.